# facing issue in loading a URL inside webview

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I am developing an android app where users can surf through different movies and play them. but I am facing a problem where I cannot load `https://www.2embed.ru/embed/imdb/movie?id=tt6806448` URL into the webview.

It plays perfectly on chrome browser but doesn't play in the webview

> this is my webView code

```java
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
webView = findViewById(R.id.WebView);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://www.2embed.ru/embed/imdb/movie?id=tt6806448");
```

> these are my logs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, to make the webview work you need to add internet permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Second, by default the webview is not enabling the javascript for the urls you provide to the webview, so you need the manually enable the javascript

```
val webView = requireView().findViewById<WebView>(R.id.web_view)
    
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.loadUrl("https://www.2embed.ru/embed/imdb/movie?id=tt6806448")
```

Comment: i have done exactly the same but still when I click on play button it's not loading the video. It shows `handshake failed` in the logs